# Grunt - Concat multiple JS files and watch for changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Still a bit of a newbie with Grunt, so please bear that in mind with your answers. I am trying to setup a task in Grunt that will concat any JS files within a directory called "custom", into a single file called `custom-concat.js`, however after running `grunt watch` (which runs fine without error), nothing is happening when I try and make changes to any of the files within my "custom" directory (i.e. console just sits at "waiting...." even after I make changes to any JS files within "custom" directory). Clearly there is something wrong with my `concat` task, but I can't seem to see what the problem is. Can anyone see where the problem lies? Full gruntfile below:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    //pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';',
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['scripts/custom/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'scripts/custom-concat.js',
      },
    },

    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: 'scripts/custom-concat.js',
        dest: 'scripts/custom.min.js'
      }
    },

    less: {
      options: {
        paths: ["css"]
      },
      files: {
        "styles.css": "less/styles.less"
      }
    },

    watch: {
      scripts: {
          files: 'scripts/**/*.js',
          task: ['concat', 'uglify:build']
      },

      styles: {
          files: 'css/less/**.less',
          task: 'less'
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see, there are three small issues with your watch task:

1. The correct attribute for watch is **taskS** not task
2. If you want to run the tasks of watch, directly at the beginning, use **options { atBegin: true }**
3. Your watch task monitors the script folder. However, this folder will also contain your concated and uglified files. So this task will run into an infinite loop. You should probably only watch the scripts/custom folder

So your watch task should probably look something like this:

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
      files: 'scripts/custom/**/*.js',
      tasks: ['concat', 'uglify:build'],
      options: {
          atBegin: true
      }
  },

  styles: ...
}
```

Github [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)

Comment: Heh I should just copy and paste this answer... a _lot_ of people are typing "task" here.

Comment: The tutorial I was following stated "task" - given that I am a newcomer to Grunt, I would NEVER have picked up on that one, as I would have assumed that the tutorial had actually been tested - clearly not! THANK YOU - this works :)